# Rails 4 Routing No route matches [GET] "/help"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have no idea what mistake I've made this is so basic:

Localhost:3000 works as my root, but if I put localhost:3000/help I get the following error:

```
   Started GET "/help" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-09 17:11:37 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/help"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/reed/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/reed/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/reed/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'static_pages#home'
get  'static_pages/help'
get  'static_pages/about'
```

end

I have the file help.html.erb under views/static_pages, below are the file contents:

```
    <% provide(:title, "Help") %>
<h1>StaticPages#help</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb</p
```

Here is my controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

    def help
    end
end
```

This is about as basic as a rails app gets. I don't know what I've done, but if you can see the typo or wherever I have made a mistake please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Go to `localhost:3000/static_pages/help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off a bit.

You have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'static_pages#home'
    get  'static_pages/help'
    get  'static_pages/about'
end
```

It should be:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'static_pages#home'
    get  'help' => 'static_pages#help'
    get  'about' => 'static_pages#about'
end
```

You can see the relevant rails documentation on this at this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)